# Como encontrar posicion en un arreglo comparando con el nombre de la variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

En un arreglo necesito comparar con el nombre del objecto, me explico me dan un codigo 61002
la idea es recorrer el arreglo y buscar si mi codigo 61002 esta en el nombre de un objecto dentro de la lista, y en caso de que coincida poner alli un valor.

```
[
{"VM_61001":""},
{"VM_61002":""},
{"VM_61003":""}
]
```

Quedando el arreglo de la siguiente forma.

```
[
{"VM_61001":""},
{"VM_61002":"dato"},
{"VM_61003":""}
]
```

He intentado con esto:

```
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){        
        if(arr[i]['VM_'+codigo].indexOf(codigo)){
           arr[i]['VM_'+codigo] = 'dato'
        }      
      }
```

Comment: Disculpen actualice la pregunta es un arreglo de objetos

Comment: El método indexOf() retorna el primer índice en el que se puede encontrar un elemento dado en el array. Pero tu quieres  comparar el valor que tienes en `codigo` con el nombre de la propiedad. Creo que ahí te serviría más [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) para hacer la condición.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi puedes encontrar el dato y cambiarlo:

```
let data = [
   {"VM_61001":""},
   {"VM_61002":""},
   {"VM_61003":""}
]

const code = 61002;
const finalCode = "VM_"+code; 

data.find(d => d[finalCode] !== undefined)[finalCode] = "Hello";
console.log(data);
```

Resultado:

```
[
    {
        "VM_61001": ""
    },
    {
        "VM_61002": "Hello"
    },
    {
        "VM_61003": ""
    }
]
```

Si no estás seguro que algún objeto del array tenga esa clave, puedes almacenar el dato en una variable y compararla antes de intentar asignarle un valor

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta me ha salvado de la duda, funciona perfectamente, siempre en el arreglo va a existir esa clave solo que tengo que buscarla, asi como esta funciona perfectamente. Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```js
var my_array = {
"VM_61001":"",
"VM_61002":"",
"VM_61003":""
};

var codigo = "VM_61002";

for(var [key, value] of Object.entries(my_array)) {
   if(key == codigo){
      my_array[key] = "dato";
   }
}

console.log(my_array);//muestra el array modificado
```